# I accidently deleted everything from my MacBook Air (Early 2014). How to recover?

Tags: mac, recovery

So I was trying to reset my old MacBook Air (Early 2014) to find some use for it, but while doing that I happened to delete everything, including recovery.

Now I'm stuck on a globe page with a WiFi selection and selecting my SSID does nothing.

How would I go about reinstalling macOS on the drive?

Comment: Have you been able to connect to a WiFi network? The spinning globe means it’s trying to find a remote boot server. Without an internet connection, this will not work. If you can’t get a WiFi connection and you have a Ethernet cable to your network router, you’ll need a [Thunderbolt to Gigabit Ethernet adapter](https://www.amazon.com/Apple-Thunderbolt-Gigabit-Ethernet-Adapter/dp/B011K4RKFW).

Comment: Do you have access to another Mac?

Comment: @nohillside I have a 2023 15-inch MBA

Comment: @IconDaemon I selected my SSID but then nothing more happens. It just sits there for hours on end

Comment: If you have access to the router, restarting it may be worth a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the description in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos/309400#309400) to download older versions of macOS (anything up to/including Big Sur (macOS 11) will work on your old MBA) and create a bootable USB stick. Then use the stick to boot the MBA and reinstall macOS.

Alternatively (as even Big Sur is rather outdated and doesn't get updates any longer), install a light-weight Linux (e.g. [MX Linux](https://mxlinux.org)) to get some more years of use out of the hardware.